# BroadcastReceiver gets called even if the app is killed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

In my app there is a BroadCastReceiver which handles the incoming calls. When there are incoming calls I call some native code methods. I dont want this broadcast receiver to be called when the app is killed after swiping. At the moment even if I kill my application the receiver is called.
The code for the receiver is-

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

    public CallReceiver(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "In onReceive of CallReceiver");
        this.context = context;

        try {
            // Telephony manager object to register for the listener
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            // Initialising the MyPhoneStateListener class
            MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

            // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
            telephonyManager.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
        }
    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state){
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        // This state denotes that the mobile is busy in some call

                            GLLib.pause(true);

                        Log.e(TAG, "Phone busy");
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        // This state denotes that the phone is ringing

                            GLLib.pause(true);

                        Log.e(TAG, "Phone ringing");
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        // This state denoted that the phone is idle

                            GLLib.pause(false);

                        Log.e(TAG, "Phone idle");
                        break;
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        }
}
```

In manifest I have-

```
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

The permission is-

Comment: Your application received broadcast because it has intent filter written in your application manifest file, Try to register broadcast for call at runtime and unregister it when you are killing your application.

Comment: also want to note, swiping app from recent apps list does not necessary means killing the app, i.e it's not equivalent to `Force Close/ Force Stop/Stop` that is located in App Manager

Answer (score 3):

Broadcast receivers have nothing to do with the life cycle of your application, Android reads your Application's Manifest and sends the Broadcasts to respective app expecting the particular action. If you wish to stop receiving broadcasts when App is not active then you need to unregister your broadcast in onDestroy of your Activity/Service

```
unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)
```

Comment: also using `exported=false` or not adding them to the manifest

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve the issue is

```
 Register BroadCastReceiver in onResume, unregister in onPause
```

Hope this should work for you.

Comment: I have many activities in my application. Will I have to do this in all the activities?

Comment: yeah In that case you need to register and unregister in every activities. Bcz onDestroy method deosnot call in few state like whenever you remove app from recent destroy doesnot call but onPause  and OnResume will be called everytime.

Comment: Should I remove the intent filter from the receiver in manifest?

Comment: yes you can register either from manifest or dynamically(Java). so remove from manifest in this case.

Comment: I have many activities in my app. Would it be correct to register and unregister in every activity. Is there not any way by which I can accomplish this through the manifest only?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way using manifest. You can centralize the code using BaseActivity, only put register and unregister code inside BaseActivity and your every activity should extend baseActivity